# SAS Array equivalent in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a dataset with following columns :

```
    ID  Measure1    Measure2    XO  X1  x2  x3  x4  x5
    1   30  2   item1   item1   item23  NA      item6   item9
    2   23  2   item1   item323 item1   item4   item5   NA      
    3   2   2   item1   item78  item3   NA      item1   item5
```

and I want to create a flag variable with this this piece of SAS Code in R:

```
 data dt2;
 set dt1;
 array x {5} x1 - x5;
 do i=1 to 5;
 if x0=x{i} then do; 
 flag=i;
 leave;
 end;
 end;
 drop i;
 run;
```

The goal is to be able to browse thorugh the values of x1-x5 and see where xo is equal to any of them and return the position , for example if item1 is found at x1 then return to me value 1 if found in position x3 return 3.

The end product would look something like this:

```
    ID  Measure1    Measure2    XO  X1  x2  x3  x4  x5  Flag
    1   30  2   item1   item1   item23  NA          item6   item9   1
    2   23  2   item1   item323 item1   item4       item5   NA      2
    3   2   2   item1   item78  item3   NA          item1   item5   4
```

Keep in mind that there might be cases where all rows rom x1-x5 contain NA, in that case i would like to return blank, is this possible?

I haven’t been able to find in R something equivalent in the sense of being dynamic (without writing multiple if statements or case when with sqldf) because now the columns might be 5 but can alter in the future to up to 20.

Any ideas?

Comment: May I recommend: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387094182 - this is not an answer, but is a useful resource if you are going to R from SAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
df1$Flag <- max.col(df1$XO[row(df1[-1])]==df1[-1], 'first')
df1
#    XO      X1     x2     x3    x4    x5 Flag
#1 item1   item1 item23  item5 item6 item9    1
#2 item1 item323  item1  item4 item5 itm87    2
#3 item1  item78  item3 item98 item1 item5    4
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset, we can replace the NA elements in the logical matrix with `FALSE` and then use `max.col`.  If there are no TRUE values in a row, we can make it to `NA` by getting the `rowSums`, check whether it is 0, change values that are 0 to NA (`NA^..`) and multiply with `max.col(.`.

```
df3 <- df2[5:ncol(df2)]
i1 <- df2$XO[row(df3)]==df3
i2 <- replace(i1, is.na(i1), FALSE)
df2$Flag <- max.col(i2, 'first') * NA^(rowSums(i2)==0)
df2
#  ID Measure1 Measure2    XO      X1     x2    x3    x4    x5 Flag
#1  1       30        2 item1   item1 item23  <NA> item6 item9    1
#2  2       23        2 item1 item323  item1 item4 item5  <NA>    2
#3  3        2        2 item1  item78  item3  <NA> item1 item5    4
```

Comment: I added some additional columns , plus that i have NA is some rows, is it a way to tackle that? cause there might be rows where all values of x1-x5 are NA, then i would like to return blank

Comment: nice one, would it be a problem of X0 was a factor and x1-x5 character for the computation?

Comment: @ArKo21  It doesn't really matter unless you are changing some values in 'factor' column with a level that doesn't exist in that column.

Comment: aha i see i am wondering why i get this message when runnign te secon line : comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for "=="

Comment: @ArKo21  Okay, I didn't test it, You could then change the column to `character`, i.e. `as.character(df2$XO)[row(df3)]==`

Comment: i run the code, the ony problem is that when there is not "hit" or the whole row is NA it stills returns flag=1, any thoughts?

Comment: @ArKo21 Forgot about that.  It is easier to fix

Comment: thank you very much again, yes this works, arrays are really different in R ,have to see the rest array statements i have how to do them based on this

Answer (score 1):

**1) base R** `as.matrix(DF[5:9]) == XO` produces a logical matrix with the same dimensions as `DF[5:9]`. Apply `wm` to each row.  `wm` is the same as `which.max` except it returns an `NA` in those cases where there are no TRUE values, i.e. if there are only NA and FALSE values in a row. If there are no such cases then we could use `which.max` in place of `wm` reducing the solution to a single line. If there is more than one TRUE value in a row it will use the first.

```
wm <- function(x) if (isTRUE(any(x))) which.max(x) else NA
transform(DF, Flag = apply(as.matrix(DF[-(1:4)]) == XO, 1, wm))
```

giving:

```
  ID Measure1 Measure2    XO      x1     x2    x3    x4    x5 Flag
1  1       30        2 item1   item1 item23  <NA> item6 item9    1
2  2       23        2 item1 item323  item1 item4 item5  <NA>    2
3  3        2        2 item1  item78  item3  <NA> item1 item5    4
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr** The main complexity here is that the data is not normalized but instead the x1, ..., xn columns are written in wide form.  To address this we can use tidyr's `gather` to convert the data frame to long form, checking whether the item equals XO and joining back to the original data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
   left_join(DF %>% gather(Flag, item, -(1:4)) %>% filter(item == XO)) %>%
   select(-item) %>%
   mutate(Flag = match(Flag, names(DF)[-(1:4)]))
```

giving:

```
  ID Measure1 Measure2    XO      X1     x2    x3    x4    x5 Flag
1  1       30        2 item1   item1 item23  <NA> item6 item9    1
2  2       23        2 item1 item323  item1 item4 item5  <NA>    2
3  3        2        2 item1  item78  item3  <NA> item1 item5    4
```

**3) Another base solution**  This base solution is inspired by the dplyr/tidyr solution.  It uses `reshape` to convert the original data frame to long form, it picks out the equal rows and then merges the Flag variable to the original data frame:

```
r <- reshape(DF, list(names(DF)[-(1:4)]), "X", "Flag", direction = "long")
s <- subset(r, X == XO)[c("ID", "Flag")]
merge(DF, s, all.x = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  ID Measure1 Measure2    XO      X1     x2    x3    x4    x5 Flag
1  1       30        2 item1   item1 item23  <NA> item6 item9    1
2  2       23        2 item1 item323  item1 item4 item5  <NA>    2
3  3        2        2 item1  item78  item3  <NA> item1 item5    4
```

**Note:** To make this reproducible we provide the code to create the input below.  Next time please provide this yourself.

```
Lines <- "  ID  Measure1    Measure2    XO  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
    1   30  2   item1   item1   item23  NA      item6   item9
    2   23  2   item1   item323 item1   item4   item5   NA      
    3   2   2   item1   item78  item3   NA      item1   item5"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```