# SAS equivalent code in R to calculate medication utilization

Tags: r, sas

I have this example of data frame. Sorry, I cannot share my dataset, but it basically resembles df.

```
df <- data.frame(member_id = c(603, 603, 603),
                 fill_dt = c("02/17/2005", "06/13/2005", "08/11/2005"),
                 drug = c("a", "a", "a"),
                 days_supply = c(30,30,30)) # could vary depending on the prescription
```

I am trying to find the proportion of days a medication was supplied over the study period (0,180 days).

The first desired output is the following:
[image]

This output is not a problem and I was able to achieve it using a combination of arrange, row_number(), pivot_wider. Basically doing what the paper did but in R. Their start day is the first time a prescription was purchased. Since the study ends 180 days after first purchase, their end_dt = fill_dt1+179. This is their SAS code for the previous output if anyone is curious:

```
proc sort data=claims; 
by member_id fill_dt; 
run; 
proc transpose data = claims out=fill_dates (drop=_name_) prefix = fill_dt; 
by member_id; 
var fill_dt; 
run; 
proc transpose data = claims out=days_supply (drop=_name_) prefix = days_supply; 
by member_id; 
var days_supply; 
run; 
data both; 
merge fill_dates days_supply; 
by member_id; 
format start_dt end_dt mmddyy10.; 
start_dt=fill_dt1; 
end_dt=fill_dt1+179; 
run;
```

This is where it gets complicated. I want to calculate the number of days a single drug is supplied over 180-days/study period. The paper in question, provides the following SAS solution:

```
data pdc; 
set both; 
array daydummy(180) day1-day180; 
array filldates(*) fill_dt1 - fill_dt11; 
array days_supply(*) days_supply1-days_supply11; 
 do ii=1 to 180; daydummy(ii)=0;end; 
 do ii=1 to 180; 
 do i = 1 to dim(filldates) while (filldates(i) ne .); 
 if filldates(i)<= start_dt + ii -1 <= filldates(i)+days_supply(i)-1 
 then daydummy(ii)=1; 
 end; 
 end; 
drop i ii; 
dayscovered=sum(of day1 - day180);label dayscovered='Total Days Covered'; 
p_dayscovered=dayscovered/180;label p_dayscovered='Proportion of Days Covered'; 
run;
```

Basically, the paper finds on which days (over 180-day period), the person took the medication. The days where there was a prescription provided (depending on days_supply variable), the day had a 1, else a 0. They then summed up the number of days covered (dayscovered) and divided this variable over the whole study period to get the variable p_dayscovered. The expected outcome is the following:
[image]

The paper is not showing all columns. their outcome includes all 180 days. So column ***day6-day29*** isn't actually one column, but rather day6, day7,...,day29 and these are populated with number 1.
Things actually get more complicated, as some prescriptions overlap. For example patient 603, purchased a new prescription a few days before the end period of the previous prescription. The way the paper deals with the overlap is by shifting the new prescription interval because logically a person would finish their old prescription to start the new one. So if the old prescription ends in 08/05/2005 and the old prescription is purchased on 07/30/2005, the new prescription period was pushed so it would actually start on 08/06/2005. A patient could have multiple overlaps so these need to be taken care off. Things are always shifted, unless a prescription is not overlapped. The paper says the following SAS code could be used within the previous code (after the second DO) to achieve the desired output:

```
 do u=2 to 11 while (filldates(u) ne .); 
 if filldates(u)<filldates(u-1)+days_supply(u-1) 
 then filldates(u)=filldates(u-1)+days_supply(u-1); 
 end;
```

The graphic representation of this would look like the following:
[image]

I guess this makes the SAS code look like this (feel free to correct me if I am off):

```
data pdc; 
set both; 
array daydummy(180) day1-day180; 
array filldates(*) fill_dt1 - fill_dt11; 
array days_supply(*) days_supply1-days_supply11; 
 do ii=1 to 180; daydummy(ii)=0;end; 
 do ii=1 to 180; 
 do i = 1 to dim(filldates) while (filldates(i) ne .); 
 if filldates(i)<= start_dt + ii -1 <= filldates(i)+days_supply(i)-1 
 then daydummy(ii)=1; end;
do u=2 to 11 while (filldates(u) ne .); 
 if filldates(u)<filldates(u-1)+days_supply(u-1) 
 then filldates(u)=filldates(u-1)+days_supply(u-1); 
 end;  
 end; 
drop i ii; 
dayscovered=sum(of day1 - day180);label dayscovered='Total Days Covered'; 
p_dayscovered=dayscovered/180;label p_dayscovered='Proportion of Days Covered'; 
run;
```

I am wondering if I could do all this using R (second, third, and fourth block of SAS code). The first part is taken care of. But I am failing miserably att calculating the days columns and overlaps. The paper in question is:  https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/forum2007/043-2007.pdf

EDIT: I am interested in keeping each day of th period as a column, just like in the photos and article provided (the day where there is a filled prescription would be a 1, else 0). This way I could calculate the number of days a person was exposed to the drug each week. This is why shifting overlapped days is important as well cause I would be able to keep track of the days.

Comment: I recognize you'd like somebody familiar enough with both languages to be able to do the translation for you; often, though, that is either unpopular (though I'm agnostic) and/or just too infrequent to be timely for you. It is often preferred to explain what you're trying to do and providing sample data (e.g., using `dput`) and expected output given that sample data. (Lacking anything more, most R users who don't know SAS will look at this code rather cross-eyed and step back slowly ...)

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the world-views of SAS and R are - literally - orthogonal.  SAS is row based, R is column based.  Therefore, a simple transposition of code written in one language is likely to be far from optimal in the other.  As a simple example: if you're coding in R and thinking of using a `for` loop, there's (almost certainly) a better way to do it.

Comment: I asked a question a while back about converting sas arrays to r code. Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280733/replicate-sas-array-in-r. Does this help get you started?

Comment: While the people in the SO community are extremely helpful, we are also 'lazy'. By that I mean we have busy lives and limited time to spend answering SO questions. Rather than expecting busy people to read a three-page article, you will get a much faster response if you edit your question to include the information requested by others, *and* a summary from that article of what you want to achieve. I think this is a useful question to ask so I look forward to seeing your updated question. Thanks

Comment: @LTyrone Hey LTyrone ! thank you for being patient with me. I just updated the question. Hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: @r2evans Hey, I just realized what I initially explained was not clear at all. I updated the question and detailed it. Hopefully it is better

Answer (score 3):

Okay I think I knew what you were trying to do when you first posed this question.

To start, the best (imo) libraries are `tidyverse` and `lubridate`. I first added more rows for the sake of providing more of a view.

```
structure(list(member_id = c(603, 603, 603, 604, 604), fill_dt = c("02/17/2005", 
"06/13/2005", "08/11/2005", "06/15/2005", "08/13/2005"), drug = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a"), days_supply = c(30, 30, 30, 60, 30)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df1 <- df %>% 
       mutate(fill_dt = as.Date(fill_dt, format = "%m/%d/%y")) %>% 
       group_by(member_id, drug) %>% 
       filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
       mutate(study_end = fill_dt + days(180)) %>% 
       transmute( days_range = map2(fill_dt, study_end, seq, by = "1 day")) %>% 
       unnest(days_range)
```

Your data should look like:

```
# A tibble: 362 x 3
# Groups:   member_id, drug [2]
   member_id drug  days_range
       <dbl> <chr> <date>    
 1       603 a     2020-02-17
 2       603 a     2020-02-18
 3       603 a     2020-02-19
 4       603 a     2020-02-20
 5       603 a     2020-02-21
 6       603 a     2020-02-22
 7       603 a     2020-02-23
 8       603 a     2020-02-24
 9       603 a     2020-02-25
10       603 a     2020-02-26
# i 352 more rows
```

This first part gets your data in long view. As mentioned the difference between SAS and R is SAS is row-based and R is column based. That's why it's important structuring the data in this way.

Then we need to create the flag and `summarise` the data by `member_id` and `drug`.

```
df_fin <- df1 %>% 
          left_join(df %>% 
                    mutate(fill_dt = as.Date(fill_dt, format = "%m/%d/%y"), 
                           fill_dt_end = fill_dt + days(days_supply)) %>% 
                    group_by(member_id, drug), by = c("member_id", "drug") , 
                    relationship = "many-to-many") %>% 
          mutate(covered_flg = if_else(days_range %within% interval(fill_dt, fill_dt_end), 1, 0)) %>% 
          group_by(member_id, drug, days_range) %>% 
          summarise(covered_flg = max(covered_flg)) %>% 
          ungroup(days_range) %>% 
          summarise(covered_days = sum(covered_flg)) %>% 
          ungroup() %>% mutate(prop_days_covered = covered_days/180)
```

The code above first takes `df1` and `left_joins` in a many-to-many relationship by `member_id` and `drug` the start (`fill_dt`) and end dates (`fill_dt_end` = `fill_dt + days supply`) of the prescription fills. Based on date ranges, this code creates a flag if the date in long format (from `df1`) is within the range between `fill_dt` and `fill_dt_end`. Then we get the `max` because of the many-to-many join.

This should produce `df_fin`

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  member_id drug  covered_days prop_days_covered
      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>             <dbl>
1       603 a               67             0.372
2       604 a               90             0.5
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! It seems correct for the first half of the question. However, given that there is an overlap between dates, which should be accounted for, I doubt it is the complete answer. Overlapped days should be shifted. I noticed that some days were duplicated when a person has two overlapping prescriptions when I run your code. 
Also, the final output of the paper has the days were a person was taking the medication.

Comment: What do you mean "shifted"?

Comment: If prescription 1 was ends on 05/august, but prescription 2 was filled on 03/august, one would assume that the patient finished prescription 1 before taking prescription 2. In this case, I would like to shift the filled date for prescription 2 by 3 days. This way, it would be "filled" on 06/august, similar to example 2 (3rd photo)